# SQL - remove duplicates from query

Tags: sql

I'm trying to create a SQL query that will not return rows that have the same No_.
How can I remove the duplicates in No_ column? I want to leave only data based on last Posting Date column.

```
select  Item.No_, Entry.[Posting Date], Entry.[Remaining Quantity], MinMax.Maximum
FROM Item
join Entry
on Item.No_ = Entry.[Item No_]
join MinMax
 on Item.No_ = MinMax.Item No_
order by  Entry.[Remaining Quantity] desc
```

The output:

[image]

but I want the output is last Posting Date:

[image]

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? `[Item No_]` is invalid standard SQL

Comment: You can use `MAX()` or `LIMIT` clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a derived table containing the latest date per `No_`:

```
select  Item.No_, 
        Entry.[Posting Date], Entry.[Remaining Quantity], 
        MinMax.Maximum
FROM Item
join (
   select max([Posting Date]) as max_Date, [Item No_]
   from Entry
   group by [Item No_]
) as e on e.[Item No_] = Item.No_
join Entry on Item.No_ = Entry.[Item No_] and e.max_Date = Entry.[Posting Date]
join MinMax on Item.No_ = MinMax.Item No_
order by  Entry.[Remaining Quantity] desc
```

Joining to this derived table filters out records not being related to the record having the latest `[Posting Date]` per `No_`.